# Rails5: fields_for only if required and if checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to implement a form that contains list of features (checkboxes, checkbox checked = feature is on), but some of features have additional options that need to be chosen if feature is checked (i.e. if user checks "additional_notification_email" then he has to provide new e-mail address).
I use simple_form.

My question is: how to:
• make additional options required if check-box is checked
• pass to controller empty hash if there is no option selected (or feature does not have additional options) and {"additional_email": "test@test.com") if option exists?

currently for each feature i use:

```
= f.fields_for "additional_notification_email" do |feature|
  .form-group#additional_notification_email
    = feature.check_box :status, id: "additional_notification_email"
    = feature.label :name, "additional_notification_email"
    = feature.fields_for :options do |o|
      = o.input......
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did (I don't know yet if it will be my solution....)
I've added some jQuery script as below to toggle options and set field value to nil when needed.

I'am still waiting for better solution :)

```
function toggleOptions(){
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
      var feature_name = $(this).attr('id')
      var feature = $('#' + feature_name + '')
      if (this.checked){
        console.log("checked")
      }
      else {
        console.log("not checked")
        feature.find(".email").val(null)
      }
      feature.find(".form-group").toggle()
    })
  }
```